# react-native-reanimated with react native version 67 Reanimated proplem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

```
enter code here
```

Unable to resolve module ./reanimated2/component from C:\Users\bdtask\Desktop\UpdatedJpo\Japyo\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js

i have updated react native version 67, and add reanimated. when i run this react native project then gives this error.

How can i solve this problem please help